# PEMDAS question: $F(x) = 3x^2 - x+2$. Find $[f(a)]^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How should I go about doing this? $(3a^2-a+2)^2$?

Thus, $9a^4-a^2+4$

Comment: Attention $9a^4-a^2+4 \neq (3a^2-a+2)^2$...

Comment: Why did you choose to tag abstract-algebra? Could you provide a little more context?

Comment: To add on to Surb's comment, in general, $(a+b)^2\neq a^2+b^2$, and $(a+b+c)^2\neq a^2+b^2+c^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To thrash an already-dead horse, I’ll remind you that just as $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$, so it’s the case that $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2+2ac+2bc+c^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** For any real numbers $x,y$ we have $$\color{green}{(x-y)^2 = x^2-2xy+y^2}, \quad \color{blue}{(x+y)^2 = x^2+2xy+y^2},$$
and note that with $\color{green}{x = (2-a)}$ and $y = 3a^2$ we get 
$$(3a^2-a+2)^2=\color{blue}{(x+y)^2} = \ldots$$

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

$(3a^2-a+2)^2$ is correct but your expansion of this is incorrect. Remember that:$$(3a^2-a+2)^2=(3a^2-a+2)(3a^2-a+2)=3a^2(3a^2-a+2)-a(3a^2-a+2)+2(3a^2-a+2)$$

You might find this useful: [expanding or removing brackets](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/Algebra%20leaflets/mc-expandbrack-2009-1.pdf)

Here is an example to illustrate the point:$$(3-1+2)^2=(4)^2=16$$If we did this using your result, we would get:$$(3-1+2)^2=3^2-1^2+2^2=9-1+4=12\ne16$$However:$$(3-1+2)^2=(3-1+2)(3-1+2)$$$$=3(3-1+2)-1(3-1+2)+2(3-1+2)$$$$=3(4)-1(4)+2(4)=12-4+8=16$$

More generally:$$(a+b+c)d=ad+bd+cd$$Now image $d=(e+f+g)$, then we would get:$$(a+b+c)d=(a+b+c)(e+f+g)$$$$=ad+bd+cd$$$$=a(e+f+g)+b(e+f+g)+c(e+f+g)$$

Comment: You lost me after a "square of a sum". How can you factor out a 3a^2 from the first trinomial and -a from the second?